# Ubuntu postfix installation error: trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 0:2.10.1-0ubuntu18

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I am trying to install Postfix on Ubuntu 10.04 using command `sudo apt-get install postfix` but there comes error as shown below:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 164023 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace locales 2.9+git20090617-3 (using .../locales_2.11.2-7_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement locales ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.11.2-7_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 0:2.10.1-0ubuntu18
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.11.2-7_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: yes, i tried that, still the error comes

Answer (score 4):

Your system is not up-to-date with 10.04, which was released with version `2.11.1-0ubuntu7` of the `libc-bin` package (now superseded by `2.11.1-0ubuntu7.5` due to a security upgrade) and and version `2.11+git20100304-3` of the `locales` package. Installing the Postfix package required an upgrade of `locales`, but the new version of `locales` is incompatible with the version of `libc-bin` you now have. It's a bug that the `locales` package doesn't declare a dependency that would have caused `libc-bin` to be upgraded as well.

Nonetheless, you are doing two things wrong. First, you shouldn't try to run a mixed karmic/lucid system. It's technically possible, but inadvisable and will lead to all kinds of problems such as the one you're experiencing. Second, you should enable security upgrades.

If you're using the GUI, bring up “Software sources” and make sure “Important security updates” and “Recommended updates” are checked in the “Updates” tab. Then bring up the “Update manager” and perform an upgrade to 10.04.

If you're using the command line, make sure `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains at least the following lines:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

(It's ok if `restricted`, `universe` and `multiverse` are on separate lines with the same prefix `deb ... lucid-...` prefix as `main`.) Then either install the [`update-manager-core`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/update-manager-core) [Install update-manager-core http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/update-manager-core) package and run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, or run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

See also [Lucid Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades); in addition to the information on this page, note that you don't seem to have security updates enabled, and the automated procedure might not take care of that.